# Does $|X_t|\leq K$ imply $\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}|X_t|\leq K$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

As the title asks, does $|X_t|\leq K$ imply $\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}|X_t|\leq K$? Context: I am trying to prove that bounded continuous local martingales are martingales, and want to consider uniform integrability. I must admit that I can’t convince myself about the arguments for this simple problem!

Comment: Does $|X_t|\leq K$ hold for all $t$? If yes, then $K$ is an upper bound of $X_t$ for all $t$ and supremum is the least upper bound, so...